# Haskell Pipes - get return value of last Proxy in pipeline

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

Let's say I have two `Proxy` in Haskell Pipes.  They represent external system processes.

```
produce :: MonadIO m => Producer ByteString m ExitCode
consume :: MonadIO m => Consumer ByteString m ExitCode
```

So I hook them into an `Effect`, like this:

```
effect :: Effect m ExitCode
effect = produce >-> consume
```

This `Effect` is going to give me the `ExitCode` from the first `Proxy` that terminates.  Ordinarily this will be the `produce`, not the `consume`.  What's the idiomatic Pipes way to get the return value of the `consume` even if it does not terminate first?

So far I am thinking this is not possible without doing some sort of icky in-band signaling so the `consume` knows the stream is done.  The only way the last Proxy knows to shut down is by getting something from an `await`, so I could send it an empty `ByteString` to signal that the stream is done.  That just doesn't feel right though.  What I've got now is a separate MVar that can provide the exit value but I'm thinking there has to be a more idiomatic way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without in-band signaling it will never be possible for the `Consumer` to have a "return value" if the `Producer` returns first. If the producer is `return`ing that means the `Consumer` must be blocked waiting for a requested value. The `Consumer` will never run again, and thus never have an opportunity to `return`,  until the `Consumer` gets an in-band signal with the requested value.

Just because signaling is in-band doesn't mean it needs to be "icky". We can convert a `Producer` that might return into a `Producer` that we know doesn't return (it's return type is `forall r' . r'`) by capturing the `return` and forwarding it downstream. We do this [`forever`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:forever) in case another request comes back upstream.

```
returnDownstream :: Monad m => Proxy a' a b' b m r -> Proxy a' a b' (Either r b) m r'
returnDownstream = (forever . respond . Left =<<) . (respond . Right <\\)
```

At the `Consumer` end you need to explicitly handle what to do when a value is `request`ed but instead of getting the response (in a `Right`) you get the return value of the upstream producer (in a `Left`).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks.  What I have come up with is something like

```
produce :: MonadIO m => Producer (Either ExitCode ByteString) m r
consume :: MonadIO m => Consumer (Either ExitCode ByteString) m (Maybe ExitCode, ExitCode)
```

so that when the Effect runs, I get a (Nothing, code) if the downstream process terminated, or (Just code1, code2) if the upstream process terminated first.  (If the downstream terminates first, there's nothing left to do with the upstream process but terminate it, so providing an exit code doesn't make any sense.)