# Signalling to downstream that upstream is exhausted

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

## Question

Using the Haskell [pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) library, I'm trying to define a [`Pipe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes-Core.html#t:Pipe) with the following type:

```
signalExhausted :: Monad m => Pipe a (Value a) m r
```

where the `Value` data type is defined by:

```
data Value a = Value a | Exhausted
```

The pipe should obey the following laws:

```
toList (each [] >-> signalExhausted) ==                 [Exhausted]
toList (each xs >-> signalExhausted) == map Value xs ++ [Exhausted]
```

In other words, the pipe should be equivalent to `Pipes.Prelude.map Value`, except that it should yield an additional `Exhausted` after all upstream values have been processed, giving downstream a chance to perform some final action.

Can such a `Pipe` be defined?

### Example

```
> let xs = words "hubble bubble toil and trouble"
> toList $ each xs >-> signalExhausted
[Value "hubble", Value "bubble", Value "toil", Value "and", Value "trouble", Exhausted]
```

### Notes

I'm aware that the [`pipes-parse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-parse) library provides the functions `draw` and `parseForever`. These look useful, but I can't quite see how to combine them into a `Pipe` that matches the specification above.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29310140/414413

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pipe like `signalExhausted` can't be defined, but a function equivalent to `(>-> signalExhausted)` can.

[`>->`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes.html#v:-62--45--62-) is a specialized version of the [`pull` category](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.6/docs/Pipes-Core.html#g:6). Execution is driven by the downstream proxies pulling data from upstream proxies. The downstream proxy sends an empty request `()` upstream and blocks until a response holding a value comes back from the upstream proxy. When the upstream proxy is exhausted and doesn't have any more values to send back, it `return`s. You can see the `return` that matters for these examples in the definition of [`each`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes.html#v:each).

```
each = F.foldr (\a p -> yield a >> p) (return ())
-- what to do when the data's exhausted ^
```

The downstream proxy needs a value to continue running, but there's no value the pipes library can possibly provide it, so the downstream proxy never runs again. Since it never runs again, there's no way it can modify or react to the data.

There are two solutions to this problem. The simplest is to [`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html#v:map) `Value` over the upstream pipe and  add a `yield Exhausted` after it's done.

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

data Value a = Value a | Exhausted
    deriving (Show)

signalExhausted p = p >-> P.map Value >> yield Exhausted
```

This does exactly what you're looking for except the function `signalExhausted` takes the place of `(>-> signalExhausted)`.

```
let xs = words "hubble bubble toil and trouble"
print . P.toList . signalExhausted $ each xs

[Value "hubble",Value "bubble",Value "toil",Value "and",Value "trouble",Exhausted]
```

The more general solution to this problem is to stop the upstream proxy from returning and instead signal downstream when it is exhausted. I demonstrated how to do so in an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29310747/414413).

```
import Control.Monad
import Pipes.Core

returnDownstream :: Monad m => Proxy a' a b' b m r -> Proxy a' a b' (Either r b) m r'
returnDownstream = (forever . respond . Left =<<) . (respond . Right <\\)
```

This replaces each `respond` with `respond . Right` and replaces `return` with `forever . respond . left`, sending returns downstream along with responses.

`returnDownstream` is more general than what you are looking for. We can demonstrate how to use it to recreate `signalExhausted`. `returnDownstream` transforms a pipe that returns into one that never returns, and instead forwards its return value downstream as the `Left` value of an `Either`.

```
signalExhausted p = returnDownstream p >-> respondLeftOnce
```

`respondLeftOnce` is an example downstream proxy. The downstream proxy can discern between regular values held in `Right` and the return value held in `Left`.

```
respondLeftOnce :: Monad m => Pipe (Either e a) (Value a) m ()
respondLeftOnce = go
    where
        go = do
            ea <- await
            case ea of
                Right a -> yield (Value a) >> go                    
                Left  _ -> yield Exhausted       -- The upstream proxy is exhausted; do something else
```

Comment: `returnDownstream` looks more like `signalExhausted` when it's written as `returnDownstream p = p //> respond . Right >>= forever . respond . Left`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this detailed and informative response. Cheers!